# How to sort a range of data based on the date i excel?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

[image]

Hi everyone,

I used the `AGGREGATE` function to extract out the row with `complete` status as shown in the output (`J3:M8`). I'm thinking to sort the rows based on the `Ending Date`, but I'm not sure how to do it by applying the sorting function together with aggregate & Index function. I also want to avoid turning the range of data into Table format. Is there any way to do it? Or at least using VBA to achieve this purpose (preferably not using VBA, if there is no other way then VBA is fine for me)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sort()` function with `Filter()` formula like below

```
=SORT(FILTER(D5:H11,H5:H11="Complete"),3)
```

Here `3` is sort index of column of return array means `Ending Date` with default sort order `Ascending`. If you want to sort in `descending` order then use Sort Order `-1` option of `SORT()` function.

```
=SORT(FILTER(D5:H11,H5:H11="Complete"),3,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun24HR, thanks for your solution. However, based on what I know `Filter` function only available for office 365 user right? Because I used the function before but some user without 365 office unable to use that. Is there another way to do that?